# How to set TERM environment variable Apache + mod_wsgi + django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I used Apache + mod_wsgi in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in deploying my django application.
Set-up and deployment is OK, given that the method in views.py returns a value when I access the URL associated with it. And also, there are no errors in the Apache error.log.

However, when I added an:

```
os.system("java -jar <java application name>")
```

to the method implementation in the views.py, a **"TERM environment variable set"** is displayed on Apache's error log, and the java applications is not executed. The java application, when successfully ran, outputs a simple text file. But as expected (and since the java app was not executed), no text file was generated.

Having that explained, my question is **How will I properly set the TERM environment variable to successfully run the java application?** I already tried this:

```
SetEnv TERM /usr/bin/xterm
```

but it did not solve the problem. I also tried these 2:

```
SetEnv TERM /usr/bin/xterm:$PATH
SetEnv TERM /bin/bash
```

but again, it did not work.
Hoping to hear your ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is with your java application; what does it do exactly?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thanks for the reply. I don't think it's the java app. All it does is read an input csv file and then write it on a different file. When I run it stand-alone, it's working fine.

Comment: The problem is when you run it standalone, you are running it from a console when TERM is set. Depending on what else your application is doing (for example, if its using `clear`), then it needs TERM to be set.  To start off with, pass the _full file system path_ to `java` and also the full file system path to the jar file.

Comment: Thanks again. I am already calling and passing, the java app and the parameter, using full file system path, respectively. I'll double check if the java app uses clear.

Comment: Just to be clear the the full path in the os.system call.

Answer (score 0):

When having issues executing sub processes from mod_wsgi, have never seen TERM as being an issue before and is generally for other reasons.

If you still believe it is non existence of TERM in your environment, then in your WSGI script file add:

```
import os
os.environ['TERM'] = 'xterm'
```

Note though that TERM isn't set to either a path or even a single executable, but a terminal type. Would suggest you go read up about what TERM is even for.